flutter app, pubspace.yaml file indentation error
i am learning flutter and i wanna learn the image widget , so i added the images in a new floder named " assets " but i got problem in pubspace.yaml file it started giving errors for its indentaion . i fixed it but still teh same error.and if i do it the wrong way it shows no error . butt when i run the code after adding image to teh body it shows a box saying that image in the assets is not loaded.or assets is empty.
indentation of yamlfile
making new project.
running the flutter powershell commmands
reinstalling the complete setup
used chatgpt but the gtpt's given code still shows errors in the .yaml file .

Does this answer  answer your question?
